# LDAP filter breaks LDAP bind on Symfony

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony4

I'm currently trying to setup LDAP on my app.

Here are the config files :

services.yaml :

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        - host: mydc.network.lan
          port: 389
          #encryption: tls
          options:
              protocol_version: 3
              referrals: false
```

security.yaml:

```
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: "dc=XXXXX,dc=com"
            search_dn: "CN=XXXXXX,OU=LDAP,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=XXXXX,DC=com"
            search_password: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            filter: "(samAccountName={username})"
            uid_key: uid
[...]
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        security: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: my_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: '{uid_key}={username}'
```

My problem is :

- If I remove the filter, LDAP binds correctly but the query string is empty (?????)

Error :

```
[2019-07-17 12:00:35] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at XXXXXX\\vendor\\symfony\\security-core\\Authentication\\Provider\\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:67, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): User \"cmx\" not found. at XXXXXX\LdapUserProvider.php:80)"} []
```

- If I change uid_key or add the filter, LDAP can't bind anymore, even tho these are not related at all !!!!

Error :

```
[2019-07-17 12:01:25] php.DEBUG: Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

Here is LdapUserProvider from constructor to where I get my error :

```
public function __construct(LdapInterface $ldap, string $baseDn, string $searchDn = null, string $searchPassword = null, array $defaultRoles = [], string $uidKey = null, string $filter = null, string $passwordAttribute = null)
{
    if (null === $uidKey) {
        $uidKey = 'sAMAccountName';
    }

    if (null === $filter) {
        $filter = '({uid_key}={username})';
    }


    $this->ldap = $ldap;
    $this->baseDn = $baseDn;
    $this->searchDn = $searchDn;
    $this->searchPassword = $searchPassword;
    $this->defaultRoles = $defaultRoles;
    $this->uidKey = $uidKey;
    $this->defaultSearch = str_replace('{uid_key}', $uidKey, $filter);
    $this->passwordAttribute = $passwordAttribute;

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    try {
        $this->ldap->bind($this->searchDn, $this->searchPassword);                  <------- this fails if I put a filter
        $username = $this->ldap->escape($username, '', LdapInterface::ESCAPE_FILTER);
        $query = str_replace('{username}', $username, $this->defaultSearch);                  <------- this is empty if I don't put a filter
        $search = $this->ldap->query($this->baseDn, $query);
    } catch (ConnectionException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username), 0, $e);
    }

    $entries = $search->execute();
    $count = \count($entries);

    if (!$count) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
    }
```

Looking at the constructor I don't see why the query string would be empty... Any idea ?

Comment: Can you confirm your ldap server is Active Directory ? In this case, in security.yaml set `uid_key: 'sAMAccountName'` and `filter: '({uid_key}={username})'`. Then for authenticating users, you would set something like : `dn_string: 'cn={username},ou=users,dc=example,dc=com'`, or if you can't build up dn like this (ie. user entries are in several ou's), you would set : `dn_string: 'dc=example,dc=com'` and `query_string: '(sAMAccountName={username})'`

Comment: Setting uid_key to samAccountName make bind fail...

Comment: *Can you confirm your ldap server is Active Directory ?* So it's not ? uid_key will depend on the backend.

Comment: It is AD. But what I don't understand is that if I put samAccountName as uid_key, the ldap bind don't work anymore!! This is totally not linked

Comment: Maybe your schema is set to be case sensitive on attribute lookup , in which case note the slight difference between `sAMAccountName` and `samAccountName`, by the way the condition in your constructor fallbacks properly with the correct case, that might explain why binding works when you remove the filter.

Comment: Ok so welcome to magical wonderland. Or maybe the land where small details can make everything go wrong. I'll post an answer...

Comment: It's not magic, it was working without filter set because in your constructor you set it in case it's null , but with the correct attribute case

Comment: I now understand that ldap_bind() failed not on searchDN credentials but on the submitted credentials. The error was not that clear in the logs... I tought that setting the filter made something getting parsed wrongly and changed the searchDN creds somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the EXACT thing to do to make it work :

```
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: "dc=XXXX,dc=com"
            search_dn: "CN=XXXXXXX,OU=LDAP,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=XXXX,DC=com"
            search_password: "XXXXX"
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            filter: "({uid_key}={username})"
            uid_key: samAccountName
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        security: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: my_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'dc=XXXXX,dc=com'
            query_string: '(samAccountName={username})'
```

And was pretty close to this once because I tried the following :

```
query_string: '({uid_key}={username})'
```

And got this error :

```
Could not complete search with dn "dc=XXXXX,dc=com", query "({uid_key}=cmx)" and filters "*". LDAP error was [-7] Bad search filter
```

Thanks for your help Eric !